# Remove responsive feature from bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a really big web project based on Twitter Bootstrap.
I need to totally disable responsive features.

But Bootstrap page instruction for disabling responsive features (see this http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive ) includes a really hard step to do : `For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.`

But I don't want to modify hundreds of .php and .html files and change all col-md-* styles to col-xs-*, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

As steps provided by bootstrap, its really hard to do change in hundred of files to achieve this. But CSS is the thing that could not get change easily by any function or script. You will need to put manual efforts.

One way is that instead changing class names in huge number of files, do edit css file of bootstrap and set common changes for classes of different resolution. Like if you have width 1200px to class ".col-xs-12" and it is working for you then reflect this change to other classes like ".col-sm-12" etc.